# Dice game probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, dice

Suppose you roll a regular $6$-faced dice. For each roll you are paid the face value. If you get $4, 5$ or $6$ you may roll again. If you get $1,2$ or $3$ the game stops. Find the expected payoff

I dont know how to approach such questions could someone please help me out?

Comment: Could you do it if it didn't have the rule about rolling again?

Comment: yes then the expected pay off will be 3.5. We can just average them out

Comment: Ok. Now, for a single roll, what's the probability that you get to re-roll?

Comment: What happens if you roll $6$ on the first two rolls?  Do you roll a third time?

Comment: 1/2 probability that i get to reroll

Comment: @saulspatz I think we can assume the game keeps going if we get a high roll, and it only stops if we get a low roll.

Comment: yes i get to roll the 3rd time. i can reroll till the time i am getiing 4 or 5 or 6

Comment: Okay, so the expected value of the first roll is $3.5$, and half the time, you get to play again.  Can you figure it out now?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you.

Comment: i think if i roll it twice it will be 5.25 i think but i dont know how to get it for all the rolls

Comment: If the value is $v$ then $v=3.5+\frac12v$.  You get $3.5$ on the first roll, on average, and half the time, you get to play again.

Comment: Here's another way to get the same thing. Treat each roll as a new game. The payout for each game is $v$. Half the time you roll (1,2, or 3), with an expected payout of $2$, half the the time you roll (4, 5, or 6) with an expected payout of $5 + v$. So $$v=0.5×(2) + 0.5×(5 + v)$$

Comment: so if i roll it twice only. the expected value is 4.5

Comment: No, if you roll it twice, the 1st roll must be high, and the 2nd roll must be low, so you get an expected payout of 5 for the 1st roll, and 2 for the 2nd roll.